# How to develop a xamarin forms component control to be used as dll in a project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I'm developing a xamarin forms class library (Custom Component) that targets (Windows, Androi and IOS) platforms "this library should be added to an existing Xamarin forms Portable project as DLL reference" and want to add a UI control and use it's native functions from inside the library. Custom renderers can't be added in PCLs so Can anyone help on how to access the control's native functionality?

Comment: You have to create nuget if I understand your question that will have separate dll for each platform.

Comment: Have a look at this [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/afead421-3fbf-489a-a4e8-4a244ecdbb1e) it saves you a lot of work and gives you a general idea

Comment: thanks @Rohit for your reply

Comment: thanks @gerald-versluis this typically solved my problem

Comment: Please let me upgrade it to an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from scratch on your by following [this piece](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/nuget/) of documentation by Xamarin on how to build NuGet packages. Then just make sure you build them without too much references and test them in your sample projects.

But to make your life a lot easier have a look at this [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/afead421-3fbf-489a-a4e8-4a244ecdbb1e) by James Montemagno. It installs some project templates for you so naming is consistent and you have the basics already setup to start building your reusable code.